# creating report with wpf and linq to sql

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports-2008

I have the following scenario:

I have quotation under the quotation there are area and software. under area I have accessories and hardware. I am using wpf with linq to sql. I need to create report that display quotation and under the quotation areas under each area the hardware and the accessory. what is the best methodology to be able to achieve this? what kind of report i should use?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at aspose. It is a nice tool for generating reports. Take a look [here](http://www.aspose.com/)